# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file of Bin\\S-1-5-21-1966573187-186149680-2580014948-1001\\$I0SFVU6.txt'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, file

I am making a program to go through my whole windows drive and index every file.
Here is my code :

```
import os
import time
cTime = (int(time.time())/3600)
os.makedirs(f"C:\\fileDoucumentation\\{cTime}")
os.chdir(f"C:\\fileDoucumentation\\{cTime}")
numberOfFilesChecked = 0

def documentFile(path):
    global numberOfFilesChecked
    for i in range(len(path) - 1, -1,  -1): #search from the back to the front of 
        #the file name for the period which marks the extension.
        if path[i] == ".":
            # the following line is the one that produces an error
            fObject = open(f"file of   {path[i + 1:]}.txt", "a+") 
            #we create a file named "file of  extension", and we set it to append 
            # mode
            numberOfFilesChecked += 1
            print(numberOfFilesChecked)
            fObject.write(path + "\n")
            #we then write the name of the file being indexed to the file we just 
            # opened, then add a line break.
            fObject.close()
            break



def loopThroughDir(path):
    try:
        for i in os.listdir(path):
            if os.path.isdir(path + "\\" + i): #if the path is a folder
                loopThroughDir(path + "\\" + i)
            else: #if it's a regular file
                print(path + "\\" + i)
                documentFile(path + "\\" + i)
    except PermissionError:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loopThroughDir("C:\\")
    print(numberOfFilesChecked)
```

The problem is, it constantly says that whenever I create a file, it says that it cannot find it, and it raises an exception:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file of Bin\S-1-5-21-1966573187-186149680-2580014948-1001\$I0SFVU6.txt'!
I am not sure what the issue is, since according to [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm) the file mode "a+" will create a file if it does not exist!

**EDIT:**
I tried the code without any of the "\" and it worked perfectly... I think that it thought I was trying to create a file in a nonexistent directory, so it raised the error.

Comment: At the very least, there's a race condition between reading a directory and the file within. You might be able to determine on error whether the file is suddenly gone as well. As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask].